# Ubuntu 9.10, systray(system tray) icons are missing

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, notification-area

I was moving some panels on the Desktop and I accidentally clicked "Remove from Panel" and now my Sound, Wireless Networks Config, Battery Indicator, Dropbox, icons are gone.

I did some search in the menus and stuff trying to find a way to put them back again but unfortunately I couldn't find them. It must be a complete panel with icons, cause I pressed only 1 click "Remove from panel", and those 4-5 icons disappeared all at once..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click on the top panel, select `Add to panel...`, then re-add the "notification area" applet.

Comment: i knew that it was that easy but i wasnt giving attention at the "notification area" panel at all:) thx a lot man!